# Convert NSData to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some problem to convert the data value using the  NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding, and i don't want used the NSUTF16StringEncoding. my question why i must using the UTF16 to convert this data? The value of this data is 
`<FEFF004F00700065006E004F00660066006900630065002E006F0072006700200032002E0030>`

```
 NSString* stringFromHexData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataValue encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

Comment: If the data is encoded in UTF-16 why do you want to use MacOS Roman?

Comment: it mean i must change the encoding of the NSData?

Comment: It means that you decode the data with the same standard used for encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use UTF-16 because the data is encoded in UTF-16.

If you want to use MacOS Roman, you must have your data encoded in MacOS Roman in the first place.

Comment: But haw I know the encoding before try to convert?

Comment: Where do you retrieve the data from?

Comment: i get the data from PDF file

Comment: 1) show some code, 2) you cannot guess the encoding by looking at the data. Either you know it a priori, or you simply try to convert it with different encodings until it doesn't return nil.

Comment: Thx Gabriele Petronella

Comment: @mobileHard: So called "text strings" in PDF use either PDFDocEncoding (which is a superset of ISO Latin 1) or UTF-16 (big-endian). In the latter case, the string starts with the byte-order marker `FE FF`. All this is documented in the PDF specification.

Comment: it mean i can use only NSISOLatin1StringEncoding and NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding  and what about the NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding!!

Comment: @mobileHard: As Gabriele said, it depends where the data comes from. What I said applies to PDF String objects that are intended to be human-readable, such as annotation, bookmarks etc. It can be completely different for some text embedded in the contents stream, perhaps using a custom font encoding. In that case it might be necessary to consult the font descriptor for encoding information (there also can be a "To Unicode" mapping). - Unfortunately, reading PDF data is not trivial.

Comment: What's your requirement exactly?

Comment: Get the object dictionary from PDF and convert it

Comment: To a string? For what purpose? Why do you need that specific encoding?

Comment: i try to get the dictionary object and i extract all the string.

Comment: So why can't you use UTF-16?

Comment: Yes i try it to use and it ok now, i think i must used it and using the ISO Latin 1 for other type of string